# Updating the queue priority automatically

Tags: mysql

I have this table which decides the order of articles to be displayed in my webportal:-

```
Table- ARTICLE_POSITION
`article_id` int(12) NOT NULL,

`article_position` int(11) NOT NULL
```

say this is sample data in table:-

```
article_id     article_position
56             1
58             2
443            3
88             4
5667           5
322            6
```

for showing the relevant article I use query to sort them according to article_position and display on webpage, Now the problem is that when I try to move any article to different position say I want to move
Article 5667 from position 5 to position 1, I have to update position of each article lying between 1 and 5,using UPDATE query

final table structure

```
article_id     article_position
5667           1*
56             2*
58             3*
443            4*
88             5*  
322            6
```

> ( * position updated )

this update query becomes really time consuming and inefficient when database is large, is there any other way of doing it....

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid re-ordering all of your articles, try using another datatype for article_position other than an int.  Go with something like a timestamp.  Then your ordering query can present the articles in order of newest timestamp to oldest.  If you need to move one article to the top, just assign a newer timestamp to its article_position element.  This should solve the problem of having to reorder all of the article_position elements in your original example.

Comment: I have to move articles around at different positions not only at the top, may be at the bottom of the list , your idea was good, but not suitable for this problem, Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

I'm making the assumption that you're looking for a solution to insert at any point in the article_position order.  I can't think of a solution where you would never have to update article_position for all article_id's, but you could offset the need to do it EVERY time an article_position changed.  Rather than incrementing each article_position by 1, add some padding for insertion through an increased position increment (5, 10, 25, 100, etc...).  This would leave room for changing an existing article's article_position without having to update all of the other articles.

To demonstrate with your example:

```
article_id     article_position
56             5
58             10
443            15
88             20
5667           25
322            30
```

After re-order (* = updated article_position)

```
article_id     article_position
5667           2*
56             5
58             10
443            15
88             20
322            30
```

Eventually, you would need to update all of the article_position's to keep from running out of insertion space between some articles.  But this could be done at some planned maintenance interval rather than every time an article_position changes.